# Is there an English equivalent of the Portuguese saying "Seven dogs to a bone"?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Is there an English equivalent of the Portuguese saying “Seven dogs to a single bone”?

Sorry for not including the detailed meaning of the expression.

“Seven dogs to a single bone” is the literal translation of the saying in Portuguese (*Sete cães a um osso*), usually used when noticing a situation of multiple people being after the same objective, as in:

- group of single and lonely males after the same seemingly accessible female who just enjoys the extra attention;
- several unemployed people after the same mediocre vacant job spot;

In general, it is the irony of the need for competition in obtaining certain things, that everyone needs or wants.

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: when poverty strikes, it's dog v dog

Comment: There's a short video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ns4KR5c67O0 that seems to suggest an awareness of the expression and at the same time mocks it...

Comment: I can't think of an English equivalent but I love the Portuguese expression and can't wait to use the translation next time I see a situation that warrants it!

Comment: I don't think  *to* ("seven dogs ***to*** a bone") is the right preposition. *Seven dogs **after** a bone* is better. The Portuguese preposition ***a*** (*cães **a** um osso*) suggests the verb *atirar-se* (you'd need a verb there if it weren't an idiom), literally *hurl oneself, jump*, so *seven dogs jumping at the bone* or *seven dogs attacking the bone* (as you might "attack" your dinner), and by implication, fighting for the bone.

Comment: Seven dogs for every bone, the Portuguese to English translator says (that would be me). In English, you can't say seven dogs **after** a bone with an implied /to go after something/ as in the try and grab). Atirar-se no or encima do osso....not /a/ I don't think. Se atiraram no/encima do osso.

Comment: @Lambie *Atirar-se a* is both European and Brazilian Portuguese. See [this Brazilian dictionary](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=atirar): 1 *atirou-se às ondas* 'hurled oneself into the waves' (dived); 5 *atirar-se aos inimigos* 'hurl oneself at the enemies' (attack).  And you don't use ***a*** for proportions, as in *102 boys born for evey 100 girls* (you'd use *por*) or  *one nurse for evey 50 patients* (you'd use *por* or *para*); *seven dogs for every bone* translates as *sete cães por/para cada osso*.

Comment: @Lambie [See this one too](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ceU7AAAAYAAJ&q=%22atirou-se+ao+osso%22&dq=%22atirou-se+ao+osso%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii69T9oIHNAhXjB8AKHbTwDYAQ6AEIHDAA) (my translation) "It was the Thin Dog who fell silent first. He had seen a fresh bone on the grass by the roadside. In a leap, he 'hurled himself' at the bone (atirou-se ao osso).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of phrases that denote competition for limited resources, but much fewer that specify a single one.

"**Winner take all**." is the best I can think of that means a singular victor and prize. (There are others but they are not appearing to mind...)

"**Cut-throat competition**" refers to competitors being extremely serious about beating each other. (literally, it means they'd kill to win) This doesn't mean anything about the *number* that can win.

"**Pigs at a trough**" is a related phrase to this, but increased distance from rural life makes it less common anymore. It references the shouldering competition at feeding. That being the image, though, it implies multiple potential 'winners'.

Many terms indicate that there is no arbiter of fairness for the competitors,

"**Catch as catch can.**" means those involved have to struggle to get anything. Can imply that multiple opportunities to progress are available but certainly not guaranteed.

"**Every man for himself.**" means the competitors aren't interested in helping the others. You're on your own.

"**First come first served.**" means whoever claims the stuff first gets theirs. Generally implies no arbitration to keep things fair.

These are often combined: "**It's winner-take-all and every man for himself out there.**" would essentially say the same thing.

You could also just use the phase "**Dogs fighting over a bone**" and you'd generally be understood.

Just be aware that "A dog on a bone" is a phrase for *working on* something. It's singular, though, which makes the differences fairly obvious.

Comment: I highly recommend using **bold** to highlight the actual suggestions so that it's better fit for speedreading. :)

Comment: @NVZ there are too many suggestions for my liking, and no external links/sources. EDIT I'm referring to your suggestion, I think that the OP should whittle down the number of suggestions. Some are better than others.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ah, yes. Btw, I used to edit others' answers to suit my style of reading, but after a [meta questioning my edits](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/8007/50044), I realized my mistake and decided to comment instead of edit.

Comment: Feel free on any of mine.

Comment: This has nothing to do with winner take all.

Answer (score 2):

[**“Dog-eat-dog”**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dog--eat--dog)

> 1. marked by destructive or ruthless competition; without self-restraint, ethics, etc.:
>      *It's a dog-eat-dog industry.*

[Cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dog-eat-dog):

> - used to describe a situation in which people will do anything to be successful, even if what they do harms other people:

Answer (score 1):

Seven dogs after the same bone would probably result first in a short [“feeding frenzy”](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/feeding-frenzy) followed by a  [“free-for-all”](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/free-for-all), full of sound and flying fur.

**feeding frenzy** noun (competition)
 a fierce competition between people who all want the same thing
(from *Cambridge Dictionary Online*)

**free-for-all**  n.
1.  A disorderly fight, argument, or **competition** in which everyone present participates
(from *American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language* via *The Free Dictionary by Farlex* [with emphasis added])

Comment: It doesn't mean a free for all. It means for every bone, there are seven dogs vying for it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the suggestions, guys. As you probably noticed I'm a newbie in this site and a bit ignorant on how this works, so, I'm sorry for any mistake.

I wrote on the OP "Seven dogs **to** a bone" because it seemed the most adequate term for the translation. "Seven dogs **after** a bone" I think would come from the Portuguese "Sete cães **atrás** de um osso", the adverb meaning *to go after*.

"Seven dogs **to** a bone", translating directly to Portuguese, I'd say it would be "Sete cães **para** um osso", which I consider to be the same as "**a** um osso". I understand the association between the proposition "**a**" and the verb "**atirar**", though. 
Also, there might be minor differences between Portuguese from Brazil and Portuguese from Portugal. Internationally, it is always considered the Brazilian as the official language.

**Pigs at a trough.**

**Dogs fighting over a bone.**

These are, for me at least, the phrases that better illustrate the situation I described.

Thanks again.

V

Comment: So it’s more about expressing the intensity of the competition?  If that’s the case, maybe “The competition is [as] stiff as a bone” would work, and in the example of the group of lonely love-starved guys hovering around the attention-starved gal there’d possibly be some double entendre in play to boot! CC: @Lambie

Comment: "Internationally, it is always considered the Brazilian as the official language." I don't believe this statement is clear. Do you mean to say that internationally, Brazilian Portuguese is the official variety of Portuguese? If that's your meaning, then I believe you should find references to prove it because I have never heard of such a thing...

Comment: ... In fact, I believe the European Portuguese is favoured in Europe while Brazilian Portuguese is favoured elsewhere (from my contact with the language abroad), and this is mostly because of the number of people speaking each variety of the language. Much like American English is favoured over British English, while neither having 'official' status when it comes to international use.